# How to append (not override) values before Html.BeginForm is submitted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a form that displays a textbox for comments. Currently, when I click on Save, I lose my old comment.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveComment", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
    <input type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
}
```

I'd like to append my new comment to the existing one instead of overriding it. How can I do something like this below?

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment += this.value)
```

Comment: When you say existing one you mean original? So if text was "foo" when page loaded and I deleted it and entered "bar", you want to submit "foobar"?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov Correct!

Answer (score 1):

you could introduce a hidden field inside your form, for example like

```
@Html.Hidden("existingComment", Model.ExistingComment)
```

and change your SaveForm Method to accept an additional parameter like this:

```
public ActionResult SaveComment(YourModelClass model, string existingComment) { 
    //here you can do something like this
    model.Comments += existingComment;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give a more comprehensive answer on how I can get this value using my post method? I don't want to change anything in my model though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option will be to add a new model property and hidden field. So if you name this property `OriginalComment`, then your view will look like that:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveComment", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OriginalComment)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
    <input type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
}
```

When you post your model you will have both original and new comment.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Although I don't want to modify my model as it seems unnecessary to add OriginalComment when I'm only trying to append it with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('#Comments').text('@Model.Comments' + $('#Comments').text());
});
```

Comment: Of course! All you are doing is appending a callback to the `submit` event of the form. It should not interfere with the default mechanism, except it appends stuff to a field. I have never tested this so you may need to do some tweaking.